# Are there any table-chart creating websites?

Tags: embed, table

I want to embed a table on my website similar to this one:

http://www.footballsfuture.com/2011/combine/qb.html

My website editor does not have a table function but I can put in  html tags such as polls found on [micropoll](http://www.micropoll.com).

Has anyone found a table-creator website out there?

Thanks,

Zutroy

Answer (score 3):

That site uses [Google Spreadsheets](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/spreadsheets/) to get that effect.

[Here's how](http://embeddable.blogspot.com/2007/04/embed-google-spreadsheet-in-your.html).